# how to call globally declared module from an imported module

Tags: javascript, vue.js, internationalization, vuex, vue-i18n

In app.js i imported the i18n module that looks [app.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFcj6.png)

that enables me to call the i18n as `this.$i18n` in vue compoenents.
The problem is on created of the component i set the locale with `this.$i18n.locale`

and i have a constants.js file that needs to access the translation function that looks like this

```js
import i18n from "../i18n";
/**
 * URL Strings constant
 * @type {Object}
 */
const CUSTOMIZE = {
    product_frame : {
        single: [
            {
                value: '360x200',
                text : i18n.t('["CUSTOMIZE.FRAME.DIMENSION.OPTION"]["PX.BY"][0]', {'0': '360', '1': '200'})
            },
            {
                value: '450x250',
                text : i18n.t('["CUSTOMIZE.FRAME.DIMENSION.OPTION"]["PX.BY"][0]', {'0': '450', '1': '250'})
            },
            {
                value: '540x300',
                text :  i18n.t('["CUSTOMIZE.FRAME.DIMENSION.OPTION"]["PX.BY"][0]', {'0': '540', '1': '300'})
            },
            {
                value: '630x350',
                text :  i18n.t('["CUSTOMIZE.FRAME.DIMENSION.OPTION"]["PX.BY"][0]', {'0': '630', '1': '350'})
            },
            {
                value: '720x400',
                text :  i18n.t('["CUSTOMIZE.FRAME.DIMENSION.OPTION"]["PX.BY"][0]', {'0': '720', '1': '400'})
            }
        ],
        multiple: [
            {
                value: '150x225',
                text :  i18n.t('["CUSTOMIZE.FRAME.DIMENSION.OPTION"]["PX.BY"][0]', {'0': '150', '1': '225'})
            },
            {
                value: '180x270',
                text :  i18n.t('["CUSTOMIZE.FRAME.DIMENSION.OPTION"]["PX.BY"][0]', {'0': '180', '1': '270'})
            },
            {
                value: '200x300',
                text :  i18n.t('["CUSTOMIZE.FRAME.DIMENSION.OPTION"]["PX.BY"][0]', {'0': '200', '1': '300'})
            },
            {
                value: '220x330',
                text :  i18n.t('["CUSTOMIZE.FRAME.DIMENSION.OPTION"]["PX.BY"][0]', {'0': '220', '1': '330'})
            },
            {
                value: '250x375',
                text :  i18n.t('["CUSTOMIZE.FRAME.DIMENSION.OPTION"]["PX.BY"][0]', {'0': '250', '1': '375'})
            }
        ]
    },
};

export default CUSTOMIZE;
```

but i cant get the set locale.

Comment: "_globally declared modules_" don't exist, a module is loaded to its own scope.

Comment: i used vuemixin, but the translation is not reactive